# React Native application is being rejected by Android Play console

Tags: android, react-native, google-play-console

I am developing a socket related application and using `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALL_LOG"/>` to get call when the app is killed. When I try to submit my application to play console it is being rejected.

This is the rejected reason I reserved.
[image: Rejected reason image]

I tried changing the Manifest file like this. `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" tools:node="remove" />` But this also not working.

Can anyone please help me how can I overcome this issue.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

If you need to **restricted permission** which contains Call log and SMS (READ_CALL_LOG, READ_SMS etc.),
you have to provide a video demonstration of your app.

Check your "Policy> App Content> SMS or Call Log permission groups" page.

For your help link:

1. Use of SMS or Call Log permission groups: https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/10208820?visit_id=638198078610470155-90090436&rd=1
2. Permissions and APIs that Access Sensitive Information:
   https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9888170